# Plesk 11.5: How to add a domain without hosting?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, plesk

As an advance note, I am EXTREMELY new to server management and I have had no real world experience doing this type of thing nor have I been professionally trained. This is mainly something I'm trying to do as a hobby more or less.

Anyways, my problem is that I want to **add a domain that I've purchased from NameCheap to my Plesk 11.5 panel without hosting a website or redirecting the domain**.

My main goal in this is using this domain to be used with an online gaming server, and I want to manage the domain *THROUGH* Plesk, where I can then forward it to route to my gaming server. I assume that to do this, I would need to add my domain without hosting in Plesk, which I am fairly certain I have done.

However, the issue is **linking the domain into my Plesk control panel**! I have no idea about how to set out about this, and any guidance as to how to do this properly would be much appreciated.

Thanks! Just ask if you need more details.

Comment: Mayba what you need is an "A" record pointing your domain to the IP of your server ?

Comment: @Alex: I think I was actually incorrect in some of my wording in the question, and I will edit it after this comment. I want to handle all DNS records through my Plesk panel, where I can then point the domain to a port on my server.

Comment: Now, maybe what you need is an "NS" record pointing your domain to the IP of your server ? –  Alex 2 hours ago

Comment: @Alex - Yes, I think that is what I'm trying to do. I know my domain registrar provides nameservers, so would I just add those to Plesk? For example, I add "dns1.namecheaphosting.com" and "dns2.namecheaphosting.com" to Plesk for my domain?

Comment: Additionally, I'm also seeing some NS records inside of Plesk for the domain that look like they were automatically generated. Rather, would I add those NS records INTO the domain registrar's side?

Comment: You want to manage DNS records in your Plesk control panel ?

Comment: @Alex - Yes, that is my end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you trying to do is possible but not practical.

The right solution for you would be - simply use the DNS servers which namecheap provides for you, and manage your DNS records using namecheap control panel.

When you define your DNS records in a Plesk control panel which resides on your own PC, this records will sit on your PC and go nowehere else. Namecheap servers will not know about those records, and will continue to use only records defined in the namecheap control panel.

I guess there's nothing very special about Plesk, and in the namecheap conrol panel itself, you can define all the same DNS records which you define in Plesk.

You can also host DNS for your whole domain or part of it () on your own PC, but it's usually not needed and not a good idea. Another option for you - so called "secondary DNS" service.